Finding the circumradius of a cyclic hexagon, given three non-consecutive sides and the fact that the midpoints of all sides are also cyclic
Cruel Geometry Question, Mock AIME-i 2015:

Let $A_1A_2A_3A_4A_5A_6$ be a hexagon inscribed inside a circle of radius $r$. Furthermore, for each positive integer $1 \leq i \leq 6$ let $M_i$ be the midpoint of the segment $A_iA_{i+1}$, where $A_7 ≡ A_1$.
Suppose that hexagon $M_1M_2M_3M_4M_5M_6$ can also be inscribed inside a circle. If $A_1A_2 =
A_3A_4 = 5$ and $A_5A_6 = 23$ find $r$.

I tried:
Well first i claimed that circle of $A_1A_2A_3A_4A_5A_6$ and $M_1M_2M_3M_4M_5M_6$ have same center but that will never be true.
I tried length bash but got nowhere.
Pls Help!! Thank You!

I am trying to solve the problem using the geometric intuition as much as possible, but at some point, algebra must come in. (A purely algebraic proof can also be given, writing equations for the circles in the complex plane using the affixes of the given six points.)
Let us draw a picture, and doing so, we will do the best in using the tiny offered symmetry. Which is the equality $A_1A_2=A_3A_4$. Without loss of generality, the circle $C=\odot(A_1A_2A_3A_4A_5A_6)$ is the circle centered in the origin $O$ with radius $r$. After a rotation of the given points on $C$, we may and do assume that the segments $A_1A_2$, $A_3A_4$ of same length are reflected w.r.t. the $Ox$-axis. The mid points will be denoted below so that their origin is clear, so $M_{ij}$ is the mid point of $A_iA_j$. Then $M_{12}$ and $M_{34}$ are symmetric (reflected) w.r.t. the $Ox$-axis, so the center $\Omega$ of the hexagon of mid points is also on the $Ox$-axis.
We arrange after a reflection that $A_3,A_4$ are in the upper half plane.
The picture we draw so far is as follows:

(We have drawn $\Omega$ as intersection of the thin orange perpendicular bisectors of the thick orange segments $M_{12}M_{23}$, $M_{23}M_{34}$.) Now where can the point $A_6$ lie on the blue circle $C$? Note that a homothety (dilation, rescaling) centered in $A_1$ with factor $2$ maps $M_{12}$ to $A_2$, and $M_{61}$ to $M_6$, also the orange circle centered in $\Omega$ through all $M$-points into a (light yellow) circle centered in $\Omega_1$ (twice so far as $\Omega$ seen from the dilation center  $A_1$) through $A_2$. But the two circles intersect in (at most) two points, so we have a construction for $A_6$.
But note that the construction for $A_5$ is exactly the reflected (in the $Ox$-axis) construction!
So we know a lot of the shape of our hexagon, points $A_6$, $A_1$, $A_2$ can be taken to reflect w.r.t. $Ox$-axis into respectively $A_5$, $A_4$, $A_3$.

At this point i have to leave geometry, and enter the algebra. We put letters (variables, unknowns) at the places that appear, and solve a system.

The point $\Omega$ is important, let it have the coordinates $(a,0)$.
Then the points $M_{23}$, $M_{56}$ are on the $Ox$-axis on the same circle centered in $\Omega$, let $s$ be its radius, so the two points are $(a\pm s, 0)$.
The point $A_3$ has thus the coordinates $(a+s,w)$ for some further real unknown $w$.
Let $A_4$ be $(u,v)$.
Finally, we know $A_5$, it is $(a-s,23/2)$.



The equations we write now are furthermore using the unknown $r$, the radius of the given circle with the $A$-points on it:
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
r^2 &= (a-s)^2 +(23/2)^2\ ,\\
r^2 &= u^2 + v^2\ ,\\
r^2 &= (a+s)^2 + w^2\ ,\\
s^2 &= \left(\frac12(a-s+u)-a\right)^2 + \left(\frac 12\left(\frac{23}2 + v\right)\right)^2\ ,\\
s^2 &= \left(\frac12(a+s+u)-a\right)^2 + \left(\frac 12(v+w)\right)^2\ ,\\
5^2 &= (a+s-u)^2 +(w-v)^2\ .
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

An elimination of variables, till only $r$ remains, leads to the equation in $r$:
$$
0 = (r - 1) \cdot (r + 1) \cdot (2 r - 25) \cdot (2 r + 25) \cdot r^{2} \cdot (2 r^{2} - 277) \cdot (2 r^{2} - 25)
\ .
$$
In our geometric case, we accept only solutions $r$ which are at least $A_5A_6/2=23/2$. There are only two matches, either $r=25/2$, or $r^2=277/2$. It is not my choice of the initial data that leads to such odd numbers, but let us realize the hexagons. It turns out that only one solution gets a "nice convex" hexagon.
Possible realizations of the above values are as follows.

First of all, the "beautiful" solution appears for $r=\sqrt{277/2}$. It is "beautiful", because $(5/2)^2 + (23/2)^2=277/2$, so we may expect some rational points to appear as vertices of the hexagons.
Well, it turns out that we have in this case $A_1=A_3$ and $A_2=A_4$, and the simple optical check in the picture:

It is the solution for $a=9/2$, $s=7$, $u=23/2$, $v=5/2$, $w=-5/2$.

The second solution we have for the nice value $r=25/2$. It is "not very beautiful", because all other variables involve radicals...
It is the solution for...
$$
\begin{aligned}
a &= \frac 34\sqrt{69}-\sqrt 6 &&\approx 3.78047815440537\dots\ ,\\
s &= \frac 34\sqrt{69}+\sqrt 6 &&\approx 8.6794576399717\dots\ ,\\[3mm]
a + s &=\frac 32\sqrt{69}&&\approx 12.4599357943771\dots\ ,\\
a - s &=-2\sqrt 6&&\approx-4.89897948556635\dots\ ,\\[3mm]
u &= \frac 1{50}\sqrt{328893-3312\sqrt{46}}&&
\approx 11.07122257198163\dots\ ,\\
v &= \frac 1{25}(23+18\sqrt{46})&&\approx5.80327758785019\dots\ ,\\[3mm]
w&=1\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
The picture:


Appendix: Solving the algebraic resulted system is a typographical problem, instead, let me insert here the solution using computer aid, here
We introduce:
R.<a,s,u,v,w,r> = QQ[]
K = R.ideal([ -r^2 + (a-s)^2 + (23/2)^2, 
              -r^2 + u^2 + v^2,
              -r^2 + (a + s)^2 + w^2,
              -s^2 + ((u + a + s)/2 - a)^2 + ((v + w)/2)^2,
              -s^2 + ((u + a - s)/2 - a)^2 + ((23/2 + v)/2)^2,
              -5^2 + (a + s - u)^2 + (w - v)^2 ])

Then the elimination is a one-liner:
sage: K.elimination_ideal([a,s,w,u,v]).gens()[0].factor()
(r - 1) * (r + 1) * (2*r - 25) * (2*r + 25) * r^2 * (2*r^2 - 277) * (2*r^2 - 25)


thank you but this problem is to be solved without and code or caclculator in under 5-10mins

Then please mention this in the question. If your interest is in understanding the problem, the above is the best answer. If you want to solve the problem in 10 minutes, then ask explicitly for a solution that best fits to this constraint. In that case no proof is required, and some argument to find some value of $r^2$ is enough. I may write a completely different answer, if any... The above shows why and how the two centers o the two circles differ, it may be of interest when in the question this is the only effort made in the direction of a solution. Links or expected answers would help too.

I'll try to give a quick argument for the values of $r^2$.

sorry for the trouble

@CalvinLin Thanks for pointing it out, it is an obvious error, geogebra shows $\Omega$ and the circle $\odot(\Omega)=\odot(M_{12}M_{23}\dots)$ as they are and should be, my description was bad. Now we have after an edit, reflecting the (zoomed) picture (link): We have drawn $\Omega$ as intersection of the thin orange perpendicular bisectors of the thick orange segments $M_{12}M_{23}$, $M_{23}M_{34}$ - i suppose that at the time of typing, late in the night, i copied a bunch of underscores and indices to have a slight change, then either did a wrong change, or no change at all... Thanks!

(We use dan's notation the $M_{ij}$ is the midpoint between $A_i$ and $A_j$.)

We use the following well-known fact: For a convex cyclic hexagon the alternating interior angles sum up to $360^\circ$.

You can prove it by angle chasing. Notice the isosceles triangles formed by connecting to the center.
This is all that we need about $M$ being concyclic.


Let's calculate one of these angles in $M$.

Show that  $M_{12} M_{23} \parallel A_1A_3$ and $ M_{23}M_{34} \parallel A_2A_4$.
Show that  $ \angle M_{12} M_{23} M_{34}$ is equal to the angle between $A_1A_3$ and $A_2 A_4$.
Show that this is equal to $ 180 ^ \circ - \overset{\frown} {A_1A_2} - \overset{\frown} {A_3A_4}$.


Show that the sum of the 3 alternating interior angles is $540^\circ - 2 ( \overset{\frown}{A_1A_2} + \overset{\frown}{A_3A_4} + \overset{\frown}{A_5A_6}$).

Hence the hexagon is cyclic iff $ \overset{\frown}{A_1A_2} + \overset{\frown}{A_3A_4} + \overset{\frown}{A_5A_6} = 90^\circ$.


Using sine rule, we want to solve the system
$$ \frac{5}{ \sin \alpha}  = \frac{23} { \sin (90^\circ - 2\alpha) } = 2r,$$
Since $\sin (90^\circ - 2\alpha) = \cos 2 \alpha = 1 - 2 \sin ^2 \alpha$, we have $ 5 ( 1 - 2 \sin^2 \alpha) = 23 \sin \alpha$ or $\sin \alpha = \frac{1}{5}, - \frac{5}{2}$. Hence $ 2r = 25$.


Notes

Alternative approach for the final step

By shifting segments around in the original circle, form a cyclic quadrilaterial $ABCD$ with $|AB| = 5, |BC| = 23, |CD| = 5$.
Apply the previous condition to show that $\angle AOB + \angle BOC + \angle COD = 2 \times 90^\circ$, so $DC$ is a diameter and  $|DC| = 2r $.
Show that $AC = BD = \sqrt{ 4r^2 - 25 }$.
Apply Ptolemy's theorem to conclude that $4r^2 - 25 = 46r + 25$.
Solve this to get $r = 25/2$.


For a self-intersecting cyclic hexagon, the condition changes to the alternating interior directed angles summing up to a multiple of $ 180^\circ$ (depends on the number of crossings). Thus, we can also derive Dan's "beautiful solution" of 1 crossing with the system:
$$ \frac{5}{ \sin \alpha} = \frac{ 23}{ \sin (90^ \circ - \alpha ) } = 2r,  $$ which yields $ 5 \sin \alpha = 23 \cos \alpha$ and so we have the $ 5 - 23 - \sqrt{554}$ right triangle, with $ 2r = \sqrt{ 554}$.



Thank you so much
